# Cannot Convert 'MyClass' to 'MyClass'

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a Stub class for Unit Testing purposes.  The Stub points to the EXACT SAME `EmployeeData` class definition, but the compiler thinks they are different, somehow.  As a result I keep getting the following message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'MeasurementContracts.Business.Services.EmployeeData' to
>   'EmployeeData'

- There ARE NO OTHER definitions for 'EmployeeData'
- For some reason it "thinks" there are 2

**What would cause this?**

[image]

**THE CLASS LOOKS LIKE:**

```
namespace MeasurementContracts.Business.Services
{
    /// <summary>A data service model</summary>
    public class EmployeeData
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        public string KnownAs { get; set; }

        public string Login { get; set; }

        public string DomainName { get; set; }

        public string EmployeeStatusName { get; set; }

        public string WorkNumber { get; set; }

        public string SystemPersonType { get; set; }

        public string PersonType { get; set; }

        public string CellPhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public string OrganizationOrCostCenter { get; set; }

        public string OrganizationalLevel1Description { get; set; }

        public string PositionName { get; set; }

        public int SupervisorId { get; set; }

        public string GetName(bool useKnowAs = true)
        {
            if (useKnowAs && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.KnownAs))
                return $"{this.KnownAs} {this.LastName}";

            return $"{this.FirstName} {this.LastName}";
        }

    }
}
```

**THE STUB LOOKS LIKE:**

```
namespace MeasurementContracts.UnitTests
{
    using OData.Client;
    using MeasurementContracts.Business.Services;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    /// <summary>A proxy stub</summary>
    public class ODataProxyStub : ODataProxy
    {
        #region <Constructors>

        public ODataProxyStub()
        {
            Entities = new List<EmployeeData>();
        }

        #endregion

        #region <Properties>

        public List<EmployeeData> Entities { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region <Properties>

        public override EmployeeData GetItem<EmployeeData>(string query)
        {
            // This is NOT working?
            return Entities.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public override IEnumerable<EmployeeData> GetList<EmployeeData>(string query)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override EmployeeData Post<EmployeeData>(string query, IEnumerable<object> parameters)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**THE PROXY BASE LOOKS LIKE:**

```
namespace OData.Client
{
    public class ODataProxy
    {
        protected readonly HttpClient Client;

        public ODataProxy();

        public string BaseUrl { get; set; }

        public virtual T GetItem<T>(string query);
        public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>(string query);
        public virtual T Post<T>(string query, IEnumerable<object> parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two different namespaces, and you need to specify which one you want to use.

Comment: @Tamas Changing the namespace path doesn't work

Comment: Are you able to replicate it in a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: Post the actual compiler error instead of pictures.

Comment: @Henk I already did...it is in YELLOW above

Comment: Hmm, yes. It got lost between all those pics.

Comment: This is a common problem when you have a base class or interface reference one dll while your class is referencing a different dll that has the same name of referenced classes.

Comment: @Assil  Great...thanks....what is the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it doesn't refer to the same class at all. In fact, the second `EmployeeData` doesn't refer to *any* class. It's the name of the generic.

Your `ODataProxy` defines a method:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>(string query);
```

which the `ODataProxyStub` implements using:

```
public override IEnumerable<EmployeeData> GetList<EmployeeData>(string query)
```

This is **not** a specialized version for the `EmployeeData` type (something C# doesn't support), but you simply renamed `T` to `EmployeeData`.

Thus the compiler thinks that the generic template parameter `EmployeeData` can't be converted to the concrete class `EmployeeData` which is of course correct.

---

What you might have intended is:

```
class ODataProxy<T>
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetList(string query)
    {
    }
}

class ODataProxyStub : ODataProxy<EmployeeData>
{
    public override IEnumerable<EmployeeData> GetList(string query)
    {
    }
}
```

---

LINQpad example to reproduce the issue:

```
class Data
{
}

class Proxy
{
    public virtual T Get<T>()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

class Stub : Proxy
{
    private Data x = default(Data);

    public override Data Get<Data>()
    {
        return x;
    }
}
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'UserQuery.Data' to 'Data'

Comment: Looks like something the F12 key would easily find, can you confirm that?

Comment: F12 did nothing

Comment: I cannot change the definition of ODataProxy

Comment: @PrisonerZERO I'm not saying you should change it. I'm just saying that you're using the generics in a wrong way.

Comment: I am working in the bounds of someone else's framework & cannot change it...is there a possible "shim or fix" on my end.

Comment: Since it's only for testing you could probably abuse `dynamic` with `return (dynamic)Entities.FirstOrDefault();`. It will compile at least, but I'm not sure if it will work as expected.